# R data.table : creating a count table of values in multiple columns by using .N

Tags: r, count, data.table

Here is my test DT;

```
a<-data.table(cluster=sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 10, replace = T), a=sample(x=1:2, size=10, replace = T), b=sample(x=1:2, size=10, replace = T), c=sample(x=1:2, size=10, replace = T), d=sample(x=1:3, size=10, replace=T))

a
    cluster a b c d
 1:       B 1 2 1 2
 2:       C 1 1 1 1
 3:       B 2 1 1 3
 4:       A 2 2 1 1
 5:       C 2 2 1 2
 6:       A 2 2 1 3
 7:       A 2 2 1 1
 8:       A 2 1 1 2
 9:       C 2 1 1 1
10:       C 2 2 1 1
```

I use `ply` package's `count` to generate a count table as follows;

```
> a[, lapply(.SD, function(x) count(x)), .SDcols=2:5]
   a.x a.freq b.x b.freq c.x c.freq d.x d.freq
1:   1      2   1      4   1     10   1      5
2:   2      8   2      6   1     10   2      3
3:   1      2   1      4   1     10   3      2
```

It is pretty ugly but somewhat serves a purpose. The output that I really wish is as follows ;

```
    a.x a.freq b.x b.freq c.x c.freq d.x d.freq
    1:   1      2   1      4   1     10   1      5
    2:   2      8   2      6  NA     NA   2      3
    3:   NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA   3      2
```

Also, I would like to group them with **cluster vectors** if possible but adding   `by=cluster` fails.  Furthermore, I've tried using UniqueN and .N, which works fine with a single column but not with multiple columns.  At this point, I'd really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Based on  your example the second row for `c.x` and c.freeq` should be NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to use `.N`, loop over the column names, group by that  column, get the  `.N` and `cbind` with `cbind.fill`  from `rowr`

```
library(data.table)
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(lapply(names(a)[-1], 
        function(nm) a[,  .N, by = nm][order(get(nm))]), fill = NA))
```

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(cluster = c("B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "C", "C"), a = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    b = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), c = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), d = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: one quick question; why is get() used  instead of just [order(nm)] ?

Comment: @akh22 Because we arre looping over the `names` which are string, and to evaluate it iinside `data.table`, either use `get` or convert to symbol and evaluate i.e. `eval(as.symbol(nm))` or specify it in `.SDcols`.  Either of them would work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count the number of occurrences of each number in columns `a` to `d` separately for each cluster.

The sample dataset suggests that the data in columns `a` to `d` is of the same type. In  this case my preferred approach is to reshape the data from wide to long format using `melt()`, aggregate the data as required and reshape back to wide format using `dcast()`.
Here, reshaping and aggregation can be performed in one step.

```
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readabilty
melt(a, "cluster") %>% 
  dcast(cluster + value ~ variable)
```

> ```
> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
>    cluster value a b c d
> 1:       A     1 0 1 4 2
> 2:       A     2 4 3 0 1
> 3:       A     3 0 0 0 1
> 4:       B     1 1 1 2 0
> 5:       B     2 1 1 0 1
> 6:       B     3 0 0 0 1
> 7:       C     1 1 2 4 3
> 8:       C     2 3 2 0 1
> ```

Now, the columns `a` to `d` contain the count of occurrences. Note that `data.table`'s special symbol `.N` is equivalent to `nrow()` (or `length()`, here ).

Alternatively, we can build a contingency table of the counts using `table()` which is less compact than the `dcast()` result above:

```
melt(a, "cluster") %$% 
  table(value, variable, cluster)
```

> ```
> , , cluster = A
>
>      variable
> value a b c d
>     1 0 1 4 2
>     2 4 3 0 1
>     3 0 0 0 1
>
> , , cluster = B
>
>      variable
> value a b c d
>     1 1 1 2 0
>     2 1 1 0 1
>     3 0 0 0 1
>
> , , cluster = C
>
>      variable
> value a b c d
>     1 1 2 4 3
>     2 3 2 0 1
>     3 0 0 0 0
> ```

Note that the normal *forward-pipe operator* `%>%` has been replaced by the *exposition pipe-operator* `%$%` (see `help("magrittr")`).

Another alternative is to create a contingency table with one row per cluster:

```
melt(a, "cluster") %>% 
  dcast(cluster ~ value + variable)
```

> ```
> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
>    cluster 1_a 1_b 1_c 1_d 2_a 2_b 2_d 3_d
> 1:       A   0   1   4   2   4   3   1   1
> 2:       B   1   1   2   0   1   1   1   1
> 3:       C   1   2   4   3   3   2   1   0
> ```

Finally, for the sake of completeness, we can try to reproduce OP's expected result which repeats the values:

```
melt(a, "cluster") %>% 
  dcast(cluster ~ variable, list(I, length)) %>% 
  setcolorder(c(1, rep(2:4, each = 2L) + c(0L, 4L))) %>% 
  setnames(names(.) %>% stringr::str_remove("^value_")) %>% 
  print()
```

> ```
>    cluster I_a length_a I_b length_b I_c length_c I_d length_d
> 1:       A   2        4   1        4   1        4   2        4
> 2:       B   2        2   1        2   1        2   3        2
> 3:       C   2        4   2        4   1        4   1        4
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
a <- fread(
"i    cluster a b c d
 1:       B 1 2 1 2
 2:       C 1 1 1 1
 3:       B 2 1 1 3
 4:       A 2 2 1 1
 5:       C 2 2 1 2
 6:       A 2 2 1 3
 7:       A 2 2 1 1
 8:       A 2 1 1 2
 9:       C 2 1 1 1
10:       C 2 2 1 1", drop = 1L)
```